# Django - Javascript files not found

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to use a javascript file for the first time in Django. I've tried putting my file in a directory called 'static/js' both in the main project directory and also under the application directory. In both cases, when I do the `runserver` and go to the page, the file is not found (I used the inspect element option in Chrome).

It says that the location it is looking for the file is '/static/js/script.js' which is what I expect (I think), but says that it can't be found.

There are various other questions saying basically the same thing and I've tried their answers but they don't seem to work...

Cheers.

Comment: can we see your settings.py and all the other things related to "serving static files"?

Comment: Hi yes I should have given more information. But apparently its fixed now. Not sure what I did to fix it - I added something to my urls.py and also put in the exact directory into my `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting.